How to make an imported extruded round shape into a flexible wire?
how can I add flexibility to various existing bent round wiring shapes so that I could animate the connecting of the wires between LED fixtures?
I have an electrical assembly of LED light fixtures made in SolidWorks that I imported into Blender and would like to animate how the 1/8" diameter wiring connects between the LED strips.
The imported SolidWorks model has all the wiring shown in the final/assembled position, so some wires are straight, some are partially bent, some bent at 90 degree angles or s-curves to fit into place.
I think the most complex part is how would I be able to add Physical Properties and Constraints to something like the existing s-shaped wiring, so that I could have the s-shaped wires be able to be manipulated from being straight in the beginning of the animation to being bent into the s-shape. Thank you kindly for any help on this :)
For reference, the red and black wires were made in SolidWorks using Swept Boss/Base command which just extrudes my 1/8" diameter circle along the sketched path. I exported my SolidWorks assembly file .sldasm as .WRL in meters to import into Blender
*Side note:
I found that:

Exporting .sldasm as .WRL in meters when
imported into Blender will keep all of the individual parts separate objects (useful for being able to moving the separate parts/objects around in Blender)
Exporting .sldasm as .PLY in meters when imported into Blender merges
all parts into a single object
Exporting .sldprt as .WRL in meters when imported into Blender does not seem to work and just gives an error message.*



An illustration would really help here. It would also help to know the topology of the imported wires, since the best way about it may be to strip them out, and replace them with Blender curves.

HI Robin, I added some "reference info" and a Blender screenshot for some additional clarity. Ideally, the red/black wire would be able to bend from straight to the positions shown in the screenshots. Thanks for any help on this.

A possible route would be to

replace all existing wires with Bezier curves. If the paths down which the wires were swept are extant, and  exportable, that would help a lot.
Activate the shipped 'AnimAll' add on, which allows you to keyframe all aspects of  Bezier control-points.

My guess is that you will only need 3 control-points per curve.
Put the origins of the curves at their fixed ends.
A wire-model, also with its origin at its fixed end, deformed along the curve with the Curve modifier, will retain its length, no matter where the far end of the curve goes, so it's relatively easy to straighten .. for instance, if you want to straighten a Bezier along the Z axis, that would be SShiftZ0.. or along a Custom Orientation made from an edge or any 2 points, ..SShiftY0



Ah this is awesome, looks and sounds like a great work flow for me to start from. Thank you!!
